# Re Row numbers query

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, duplicates, row-number

I have a requirement as below:

Students and Parents login details need to be mail merged to send out letters

On our database most of the students have single parent contact and few have 2

I am writing a query(below) to give details of Students and Parents along with Username - StudentID_1 or StudentID_2 (depending on no of parents) 
auto generated password.

What we would to do is if a student has single parent then only their contact details need to show up in my query instead of extra id's

I am struggling to achieve this in my query so any help is very much appreciated.

```
SELECT StudID, StudName, RTRIM(StudID) + '_1' AS Parent_Username, CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 AS VARCHAR(1))
+ CHAR(ASCII('a') + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25) + CHAR(ASCII('A') + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25) + LEFT(NEWID(), 5) AS Parent_Password
FROM
Student

StudId   StudName          Gender Parent Username  Parent Password
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       0iCCA086
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       6jI247CA
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       7xA1075E
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       3dFCBCCF
09056750 Daniel O'Sullivan   M     09056750_1       6tC76C96
09057033 Daniel Geggus       M     09057033_1       9gXDB414

And we have Parents Portal table which has below data
StudentID    Name               ParentUsername   ParentPassword 
9054828 Lewis   Alexander          09054828_1       l5oXYQo
9054828 Lewis   Alexander          09054828_2       70AYvbi
9056750 O'Sullivan  Daniel         09056750_1       1OnVMn0
9056750 O'Sullivan  Daniel         09056750_2       rT47Sx5
9057033 Geggus  Daniel             09057033_1       Ap6EV3v
9057033 Geggus  Daniel             09057033_2       Ar4AQ22
```

So once I join my original query to Parents Portal table I see as below

```
   StudentID    Name               ParentUsername   ParentPassword 
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       0iCCA086
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       6jI247CA
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       7xA1075E
09054828 Alexander  Lewis    M     09054828_1       3dFCBCCF
9056750      Daniel O'Sullivan     09056750_1        1OnVMn0
9057033      Daniel Geggus         09057033_1        Ap6EV3v
```

i.e Even though a student has 2 parents results getting doubled ( 4 rows instead of 2)

Any ideas or suggestions how can I restrict the repeating rows?

Thanks
Ar

Answer (score 1):

You can use  RANK() OVER (PARTITION By StudID order by  ) in a common table expression or a subquery and then filter only rank=1 .

```
with query as (
SELECT 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION By StudID  order by <column parent related>)  as rank,
StudID, 
StudName, 
RTRIM(StudID) + '_1' AS Parent_Username, 
CAST(
     ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 AS VARCHAR(1)) 
    + CHAR(ASCII('a') + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25) 
    + CHAR(ASCII('A') + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25) 
    + LEFT(NEWID(), 5) AS Parent_Password
FROM Student)
select StudID,StudName,Parent_Username, Parent_Password from query where rank = 1
```

See [windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms176102.aspx) for details

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But I am getting below error:
Msg 102, State 1 , Line 12: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: try to add incrementally each column in CTE and main select too to find out which is the problem. A similar solution can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ccbc7/8)